# Google-chrome open url with hashtag

Tags: bash, google-chrome

I try to program a bash script that open a pdf file with google-chrome at a specific page :

```
google-chrome '~/myFile.pdf#page=125' &
```

but chrome convert it to :

```
~/myFile.pdf%23page=4
```

so I get a "can't find your stuff" error. 
Any idea of a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open it with the fully qualified path instead of relative. You can change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

function realpath() {
    echo "$(cd $(dirname $1); pwd)/$(basename $1)"
}

url=$1
qualifiedurl=$(realpath $url)
google-chrome "file///${qualifiedurl}"
```

And invoke it as

```
./launch-script.sh ~/myFile.pdf#page=4
```